# Regex does not return all the argument

Tags: regex, parsing

I try to parse a expression like this with my regex:

```
FIRST SECOND ARG1=$value ARG2="with space"
```

There can be any number of arguments.

example: `HELLO VERSION MIN=$min MAX=$max USER="xxx" PASSWORD="yyy"`

result: `HELLO - VERSION - PASSWORD - "yyy"`

desired result: `HELLO - VERSION - MIN - $min - MAX - $max - USER - "xxx" - PASSWORD - "yyy"`

My regex is `([\w\d]+) ([\w\d]+)(?: ([\w\d]+)=("[^"]*"|[^" ]*))*`

However, I do not get all the arguments, but only the last back. How can I fix it? It is too much for a regex?

Comment: Why cant you do a `substitution` instead of a `match`? [check here](https://regex101.com/r/nyAO15/1)

Comment: This would then not work if an argument contains spaces: HELLO VERSION MIN=$min MAX=$max USER="x  xx" PASSWORD="yyy"

Comment: In a way do you need the `-` part or do you just need to capture all the relevant values?

Comment: I only put them there to illustrate what was "found".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match what's between quotes first, then the rest.

`(["].*?["])|([[:alnum:]_\$]+)`

Test [here](https://regex101.com/r/xKcHPM/1)